# Python Numpy: perform arithmatic operations on array of numpy objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have multiple data values saved in the database. I just want to perform arithmetic action. Below is the sample of data:-

```
items = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    "+",
    5
]
```

I have above mentioned array of data. Is there any posiblity by which I can perform arithmetic action?
Actually, I want to execute above data something like this

**Code**

```
from numpy import np

result =  np.array([1,2,3,4,5]) + np.double(5)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[ 6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First be clear about terms.  I see a list that contains a list of numbers, a string and a number.  `np.array(items[0])+items[2]` is the simplest, but may not be as general as you'd like.

Comment: @hpaulj in list, I have arithmetic operators between them. like in example at first index, I have array of integers, at second index, I have operator "+" and at third index, I can have integer or float value. are you getting my point?

Comment: That's how you intend to use those items, but that's not what those items are.  There's no magic to read you intentions.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, intentions are hard to work with. But assuming the following constraints:

Input:

- The first item is always a list, int or float
- The second item is always an operator (+, -, /, *, etc...)
- The third item is always a list, int or float

Logic:

- If the first and third items are lists, they have the same length

You can use the [numexpr](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/user_guide.html) library to solve your question like this:

```
import numexpr as ne
import numpy as np


def parser(items):
    a, operator, b = items


    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)

    return ne.evaluate(f"a {operator} b")
```

Some examples and tests:

```
tests = [
    {
        'items': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], '+', 5],  # Integer
        'answers': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    },
    {
        'items': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], '+', 5.],  # float
        'answers': [6., 7., 8., 9., 10.]
    },
    {
        'items': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], '*', 5],  # multiplication
        'answers': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
    },
    {
        'items': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], '+', [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],  # list addition
        'answers': [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
    },
]

for test in tests:
    reply = parser(test['items'])
    assert all(x == y for x, y in zip(reply, test['answers']))
    print(reply)
```

Output:

```
[ 6  7  8  9 10]
[ 6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
[ 5 10 15 20 25]
[ 3  5  7  9 11]
```